# como limpiar los inputs despues de un cloneNode a un div

Tags: javascript, html

bien lo que deseo hacer es limpiar el valor de los inputs al momento de clonar un div con cloneNode

Resulta que al clonarlo me clona tambien el value de los inputs y he intetado resetarlos pero no encuentro una forma de que fucione

aqui mi **html**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                <title> </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
                        <div class="card shadow">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <b>Test de creacion</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body" id="content">
                                <div class="card mb-3" id="fath">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row g-3 mt-3 mb-3">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                 <label>Nombre</label>
                                                 <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="juan">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                 <label>Apellido</label>
                                                 <input type="text" name="apellido" class="form-control" value="perez">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="crear">Agregar</button>
                                <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="crear">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </body>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script>
                var btn = document.getElementById('crear');
                const padre = document.getElementById('content');

                btn.onclick = function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    const div = document.getElementById('fath');
                    const copia = div.cloneNode(true)
                    padre.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', copia)
                }
            </script>
            </html>
```

En conclusion quiero boorar el valor de los inputs y dejarlos vacios a la hora de clonarlos

como lo hace:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como quiero que se ejecute:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No es tan difícil, puedes usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), para obtener todos los `input`, luego usas [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para recorrer todos y les pones de atributo `value` un string vacío.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('fath');
const copia = div.cloneNode(true);
copia.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(e => e.value = "");
padre.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', copia);
```

Comment: Agradesco la repuesta aun no lo he probado pero leyendolo se ve que funciona